# How can I use an observable to perform a recursive search without going over duplicates?

Tags: rxjs

I'm going to phrase the question in rxjs, but I suppose it's similar for any Rx or observable library.

Say I have an observable of users, and a function `getAssociates(user)` that returns another observable of users. I want to use the `getAssociates` function on every user in the observable and return an observable of those associates. `flatMap` is enough for this.

But I also want to run `getAssociates` on each associate that comes back, but without ever running it twice on any given user (since two users might share an associate, and if A has B as an associate, then B also has A as an associate).

Something like the [`expand`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html) operator is what I think I'm looking for:

`seedUsers.pipe(
    expand(user => getAssociates(user)),
);`

but how can I get in the bit about not running twice on any given user? I could maintain a list of seen users, but I'd like to achieve it in a functional style.

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you need to :

- Keep track of the known users, for example using a `Set`
- Filter the known users before making a request, for example using `filter` operator

Here is a suggestion :

```
let knownIds = new Set();

getAllItems(Ids){
   return from(Ids).pipe(
     filter(id => ! knownIds.has(id)),
     concatMap(id => getAllItems(id)),
     map( id => knownIds.add(id))
   )
}

getAllItems([originalId]).subscribe( allItems=> console.log)
```

Notes:

- I guess you could manage to do it using rxjs, but none of the solutions I can think of is simpler than using a set + filter.
- I used `concatMap` to ensure you don't run the request twice. Using `mergeMap (flatMap)`, you could have a scenario like this :

---------Req(user1)----------------------------resp(user1)-------------------------

---Req(user2)--------resp(user2)--Req(user1)-----------------resp(user1)-

But if you accept having eventually more than 2 requests per user, you can use flatMap to gain speed.